# Required Products when creating opportunities

Tags: custom

I need to make a required rule or validation rule, when creating or editing an opportunity they have to select the price book and product. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Do not make the validation rule "On Create", because it's not possible for a child record to be linked to a parent record before validation rules would fire. In fact, to be safe, you'd usually want to wait until the user attempts to change to a certain stage:

```
AND(NOT(ISNEW()), NOT(HasOpportunityLineItem), ISPICKVAL(StageName, 'Some Stage'))
```

Comment: I think the field is `HasOpportunityLineItem`

Comment: @crop1645 Thanks. It's been over a year since I've had to use a validation rule like this :(

Answer (score 0):

When ever an opportunity is edited you can prompt to add a product. But the Product is a related list and using validation rule is not feasible, so here you can do as follows.

Create a number field and update it to 1 when a new product is added using work flow or trigger.
Create a validation rule and check if the number field is not equal to 1. fire the validation rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the SFDC OOB Add products button, the Opportunity must already exist so you can't create a Validation Rule requiring products on inserting a new Opportunity.

If updating an Opportunity, you have access to `Opportunity.HasOpportunityLineItem` that you can use in a Validation Rule as in

```
NOT(ISNEW()) && NOT(HasOpportunityLineItem)
```

You can also use a formula field called 'Alerts' on the Opportunity page layout that displays a text/image message indicating if the Opportunity has no Products - reminding the user who created a new Opportunity that they need to add a product.

However, if you are feeling adventurous, you can replace the New Opportunity button with a VF page and controller and enforce that a Product/Pricebook be part of the "New" button event/page that collects opportunity name, amount, stagename, closedate, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and it become obvious that the best approach was to override the standard new opportunity page with a custom visualforce page. This page offered some shortcuts to the end user (offers predefined pickling of existing contacts to add to the opportunity or offer to create a new contact), but also ended up as a guiding wizard. So on save would redirect to price book selection then to product selection. We don't actually enforce that a product has to be added but it is implied and 99% of the time one is included.  We found this to be more user friendly than validation rules and means that the opportunity is created with as much information as possible at the point or creation.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a standard function no in Salesforce. By following the directions below, you can make products required on your opportunities.

1. When logged in as an Administrator, click on:

   Setup | App Setup | Customize | Opportunities | Settings.
2. Check the box labeled "Prompt users to add products to opportunities" and click "Save".

There are some known issues that will not enforce this behavior, such as creating an opportunity on lead conversion, or cloning an opportunity without products. You can read more [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003656&language=en_US).